# How do I make the link and text appear when I hover over the div?

Tags: html, css

Basically, I've created a div, and created a hover function so that when I hover over it, it changes the color, how would I make it also change the color of the text inside the div at the same time? And how would I make the link appear as well.

CSS:

```
.NavPageDiv:hover {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-style: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #262626 !important;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color: #94f211;
}

.NavDivDiv:hover {
    background-color: #94f211;
    text-color: #262626;
    z-index: 90;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav class = "NavMainDiv">
   
    <div id="NavPremiumDiv" class="NavDivDiv">
        <h3 class="PageMain" id="NavPagePremium"><a class="NavPageDiv" href="status.html">Void Premium</a></h3>
    </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: You have a lot of `id` elements, which in CSS are `#idName` and so these will overwrite any `class` element values set in your CSS. For example your `.NavDivDiv` rules will be completely overwritten by rules set in the `#NavPremiumDiv` id.

Comment: Please read about [**CSS Specificity**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) as well as [**this guide**](https://getflywheel.com/layout/css-specificity-guide/) and further information as to [**how :hover works**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)

Comment: Hiya, I went through seeing what would have overwritten what, and I have completely eliminated several of the ID's.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have `hover` on your `.NavPageDiv` which takes precedence over your div class.  So remove the `hover` from `.NavPageDiv` and follow the css I have in the snippet below.  I hope this is what you're looking for.

```css
.NavPageDiv {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-style: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    //color: #262626;
    text-decoration:none;
    //background-color: #94f211;
}

.NavDivDiv:hover {
    background-color: #94f211;
    color: #262626
    z-index: 90;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<nav class = "NavMainDiv">
   
    <div id="NavPremiumDiv" class="NavDivDiv">
        <h3 class="PageMain" id="NavPagePremium"><a class="NavPageDiv" href="status.html">Void Premium</a></h3>
    </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: Hiya! I tried this, however I've still got to go further into the box, and hover over the text itself for the text to become visible over the div!

Comment: @pie then you need to set a class on the container div, because it seems that you only have the hover class set on your text.  You need to show your html so that we can see where your hover is taking place.

Comment: Hiya! I just added my HTML onto the original post,

Comment: @pie thank you, but is there anything inside those divs at all?

Comment: Nope, all that HTML is all of my NAV so far, I can send my whole CSS document if you like? I'm extremely new to HTML, so the formatting and structure of it all is very bad.

Comment: @pie I see, you have a class set on your ```a``` tag that is overriding the hover for ```NavDivDiv```